# Creating dummies with apply in R

Tags: r, apply

I have data about different study strategies for individuals (stored in columns labeled StrategyA, StrategyB, StrategyC. The strategies are coded 1-15. I want to create a dummy for each strategy (e.g. strategy1, strategy2, etc) because each student can list up to 3 strategies.

Example Data

```
   ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
   Strategy_A = c(10, 12, 13, 1, 2)
   Strategy_B = c(1, 2, 1, 4, 5)
   Strategy_C = c(2, 3, 6, 8, 15)
   all = data.frame(ID, Strategy_A, Strategy_B, Strategy_C)
```

I thought about using apply and creating a function linked to the fastDummies package.

```
     dummies = function(x){
     dummy_cols(x)
     }

    new = apply(all [,-1], 2, dummies)
    new = as.data.frame(new)
```

However, this creates dummies for StrategyA_1 StrategyA_2 StrategyA_3 rather than summarizing the dummies as Strategy1 Strategy2 Strategy3. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Sounds like you're interested in creating a dummy for each combination of the three variables? In which case you might need to create a another variable that combines them and then create the dummy variables from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a small transformation of `all`, you can use `dummy.data.frame()` from `dummies` (you can also use `dummy_cols()` from `fastDummies`) and then `aggregate` per `ID`.

```
all <- data.frame(ID = rep(all$ID, 3),
                  Strategy = c(all$Strategy_A, all$Strategy_B, all$Strategy_C)) # data frame "all" with one column Strategy
library(dummies)
all <- dummy.data.frame(all, "Strategy") # or fastDummies::dummy_cols(all, "Strategy")
aggregate(. ~ ID, all, sum) # since strategies are now dummies, the sum will always be 0 or 1
# output
  ID Strategy1 Strategy2 Strategy3 Strategy4 Strategy5 Strategy6 Strategy8 Strategy10 Strategy12 Strategy13 Strategy15
1  1         1         1         0         0         0         0         0          1          0          0          0
2  2         0         1         1         0         0         0         0          0          1          0          0
3  3         1         0         0         0         0         1         0          0          0          1          0
4  4         1         0         0         1         0         0         1          0          0          0          0
5  5         0         1         0         0         1         0         0          0          0          0          1
```

Answer (score 0):

I provide a method with the `tidyverse` way.

```
library(tidyverse)

new <- all %>% gather(select = -ID) %>%
               mutate(key = NULL, num = 1) %>%
               spread(value, num)

#   ID  1  2  3  4  5  6  8 10 12 13 15
# 1  1  1  1 NA NA NA NA NA  1 NA NA NA
# 2  2 NA  1  1 NA NA NA NA NA  1 NA NA
# 3  3  1 NA NA NA NA  1 NA NA NA  1 NA
# 4  4  1 NA NA  1 NA NA  1 NA NA NA NA
# 5  5 NA  1 NA NA  1 NA NA NA NA NA  1

new[is.na(new)] <- 0
new

#   ID 1 2 3 4 5 6 8 10 12 13 15
# 1  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0  1  0  0  0
# 2  2 0 1 1 0 0 0 0  0  1  0  0
# 3  3 1 0 0 0 0 1 0  0  0  1  0
# 4  4 1 0 0 1 0 0 1  0  0  0  0
# 5  5 0 1 0 0 1 0 0  0  0  0  1
```